# Trigger a stage in AWS CodePipeline using Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline, aws-event-bridge

It's possible to use AWS Lambda to trigger CodePipeline but is it possible to target a specific stage in CodePipeline with Lambda (or EventBridge, or CloudWatch)? In general, I'm building a CI/CD pipeline where CodeBuild stage starts another Lambda that launches EC2 where I build and push Docker image to ECR. Next, I need to get control back to CodePipeline. I created an EventBridge rule that listens to successful PUSH command to ECR. With that rule I can launch a Lambda but can I use this Lambda to trigger next stage in CodePipeline?

Comment: It is weird that you are trying to invoke lambda to get an ec2 up and running to build docker, I believe you can build docker image right on codebuild [aws sample codbuild docker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html)

Comment: It's a Windows OS Docker image for legacy .NET Framework 4.8 applications that I'm building using EC2. CodeBuild is for Linux based Docker images.